# To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap. It currently has approximately 3641 MB

Tags: android, android-studio

It works fine in above 5.0 devices. Other than **multidex** support is there any solution for this problem ?

**Detail** :

```
To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap.
It currently has approximately 3641 MB.

For faster builds, increase the maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon to more than 4096 MB.
To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096M in the project gradle.properties.

For more information see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html
Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.> 
    com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
    com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
    com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:  
    org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException:
    Process 'command '/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_71/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

I tried below solutions. Error is still not gone.

**gradle**

```
buildTypes {

    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
}
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries true
    javaMaxHeapSize "3g"
    incremental true
    dexInProcess = true
}
```

**gradle properties**

```
     org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a great official [article](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#about) about the 64k limit. You basically have a number of options:

- review the dependencies and remove those that are not needed or can be replaced by smaller ones
- configure ProGuard to remove unused code
- implement MultiDex in your app

Regarding "Gradle daemon needs a larger heap", this is not a problem, rather an optimization tip.